# How to eliminate static from 3200 sq foot synthetic skating rink?

Tags: static

Because of high costs, I changed from a real ice rink to a synthetic rink last winter.  For the summer, instead of ice skating, I'm using the synthetic "ice" for roller skating.  The skates have plastic wheels, which is creating a huge static electricity problem. I haven't found information from other rinks that have faced this situation and I'm struggling to find a solution. Can I ground 3200 sq foot of synthetic ice by attaching a grid of copper adhesive tape to the underside of the plastic "ice" panels?  If the panels are grounded in that way, will skaters still shock each other and the dashers whenever they make contact?  If the dashers were grounded, would skaters discharge the static every time they touch a dasher without getting shocked?  I'm open to creative ideas, I just need a cost-effective solution.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The grid needs to connect to every other panel and it would help but only somewhat by giving trapped charge a shorter distance to travel to get to a conductor where it can then expediently travel to equalize. Might as well just line the entire floor with aluminum foil. Cheaper. It would be nothing like grounding a metal structure and would not help against rapid charge accumulation. Grounding dashers does nothing without also grounding the ice (or connecting them together. Increase the humidity? You would need to ground the ice and dashers to each other. Increase humidity?

Comment: Increase humidity

Comment: Spreading some coaldust?

Comment: Aircraft add corona dischargers to wing trailing edges. Some look like copper braid with frayed ends. It might put an upper limit to accumulated voltage. Others just have a very sharp end.

Comment: Constant alpha particle emission from some radioactive source. Prevents all static build up. Might kill the users though. Demonstration: https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZBHIp967TD8

Comment: Anti-static carpet spray maybe ... ? Would likely need to be allowed to dry thoroughly and reapplied regularly though.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but in many cases this problem will not have a 100% reliable solution, or the solution will not be much cheaper than having real ice. You get what you pay for, to an extent. And there's a big danger of a non-reliable solution: it will spook people way more than constant shocks. Constant shocks are expected. But when you inform the customer that the static problem is "fixed" or "reduced", people will be getting shocked occasionally. As far as I can predict such things, this will spook them more... maybe I'm wrong of course. YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

The synthetic material manufacturer has goofed big time. Synthetic materials for any sort of pedestrian traffic, including skating, must have a controlled minimum bulk conductance, so that they would be static-dissipative. This bulk conductance must be *specified* in the material specs, and as a customer you must hold the manufacturer accountable to meet this spec.

With the material you got, the only 100% solution will be to replace it with something manufactured by people with a clue. Because to me, a synthetic skating rink material manufacturer that doesn't know about the need for static electricity dissipation should not be in the business, for they are clueless about the basic requirements their product must fulfill.

You have every right to be angry at the manufacturer.

I'm not a lawyer, but to me a non-dissipative rink material fails to meet the basic requirement of fitness for purpose it's sold for. You should talk to a lawyer and see if this failure on the part of the manufacturer would have some remedies in the law.

Anyway, you will be replacing that material if you want to fix the problem. Everything else will be a poor-man's fix that will drive away the customers.

You should be prepared to find a vendor who knows what on Earth they are doing, buy new material from them, have a consultant EE do acceptance testing for you to ensure they didn't cheat you on bulk conductance, and finally replace the surface of your rink.

I'm afraid there are no better news I can give you. There are no bandaids here that would work all the time, and/or whose application and maintenance will be burden to deal with. Never mind that skating tends to aerosolize whatever surface treatment you'd apply to the bad material to make it static-dissipative. And people will be breathing this stuff in. Does the supplier of a static-dissipative surface treatment solution specify it as safe for use in such an environment where considerable amount of it will turn to dust and be inhaled? I'm not holding my breath that you'll find anyone willing to supply you with that material for the use you have in mind, because it's extra liability for them. In fact, you can tell if a vendor has their head on straight by how they react to the information about how their surface treatment would be used. They need to understand the dust creation potential etc.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a copper ground plane underneath the layer of nonconductive plastic would actually *increase* the intensity of shocks, by raising the *capacitance* (the shocks would be at lower voltage,  but higher current, so more noticeable).

As mentioned, there are various [anti-static agents](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductCatalog_EN/1816.htm) that can be applied to the rink surface *and to the plastic wheels and to the boots*. There are a few concerns you would have in doing so.

- The agent must be nontoxic and nonallergenic, not only while being applied, but on a surface where someone might fall and have a skin abrasion.
- It must, of course, be economical, particularly since it would need to be applied to an entire rink, perhaps 1,800 m<sup>2</sup>.
- It must not degrade the experience of skating, e.g., by making the surface too slippery for lateral traction. You might need to experiment to find one to meet that criterion.

Comment: To me, the biggest danger is the inevitable conversion of the surface treatment to dust, and inhalation hazards. Who will be willing to warrant their material as fit for purpose when there's reasonable potential for people to inspire the dust? Unless there's lots of experience with environmental exposure to such dust, this could be a big snafu. A kid gets asthma after skating and the lawyers figure out such a treatment was applied and it will be a royal ****show :(